# Update Info.plist string from a config file by looking up the key

Tags: bash, shell

I need to update a plist string from a config file by looking up the key. if the key matches between the info.plist and the config file, then replace the string from the info.plist with the value from the config file.

qa.xcconfig:

```
username=newUserName
password=newPassword
```

info.plist

```
<key>username</key>
<string>oldUserName</string>
<key>password</key>
<string>oldPassword</string>
```

Code Attempt:

```
 awk  -F= 'FNR==NR{QADIC[$1]=$2;next} {for (i in QADIC){
$(rlwrap /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :i 'QADIC[i]'" Info.plist)
}
}' qa.xcconfig
```

- Created a dictionary from my develop.xcconfig
- For each key in the dictionary, if the key in the plist matches then replace the string.

Expected output:

```
<key>username</key>
<string>newUserName</string>
<key>password</key>
<string>newPassword</string>
```

I don't seem to able to get the for and if working together.

Comment: You will get help much faster if you post expected output.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I have added the expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my issue as below:

```
QA_KEY_ITEMS=($(awk -F'=' '{print $1}' < qat.xcconfig))
QA_VALUE_ITEMS=($(awk -F'=' '{print $2}' < qat.xcconfig))
for ((i=0;i<${#QA_KEY_ITEMS[@]};i++))
do
    key=${QA_KEY_ITEMS[$i]};
    value=${QA_VALUE_ITEMS[$i]};
    rlwrap /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :$key '$value'" Info.plist;
done
```